# WP: Using advanced custom fields to input Vimeo ID into iframe code

Tags: wordpress, vimeo

I have used this in other situations and seems to work, but vimeo throws up an error...

```
<?php 
    echo '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/';
        the_field('vimeo');
    echo ' title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="1000" height="565" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<?php 

$videoID = get_field('vimeo');

echo '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'.$videoID.'&amp;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="1000" height="565" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>';

?>
```